# Publish root CA and sub ca certificate to the Trusted root certificate store

Tags: certificate-authority

I have a root CA which is standalone and I have subordinate CA which is domain joined. I recently renewed the certificate of my root CA and sub CA. How do I push these certificates in the trusted root certificate store on client machines.

Comment: What OS and software are the client machines running?

Answer (score 12):

There are two methods.  You can either use Group Policy to distribute the certificates to domain clients, or you can use `certutil.exe -dspublish -f <certfilename> RootCA`.  There are advantages to either method. The `dspublish` method is simpler, but the Group Policy method is a bit more flexible. Using Group Policy, you can scope the recipients of the certificate(s) to certain OUs, configure extended properties like Extended Validation, OCSP responders, etc.

[image]

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782744(v=WS.10).aspx

OR

[image]

But you do not need to do both.

Comment: What is the precise method to export the certificate to <certfilename> - what is the correct format?