# Can Standalone (online) CA + Subordinate Enterprise CA configuration issue valid intranet SSL certs?

Tags: active-directory, ssl-certificate, domain-controller, certificate-authority

The question is purely about whether this config is *capable* of **issuing valid intranet SSL certs** (i.e. SSL certs for internally facing sites), and not any other implications or concerns.

(The focus of the question isn't security, availability, continuity, disaster recovery or any other implications or concerns other than the ability to issue valid SSL certs.)

Context: inherited an AD setup where the primary DC has a CS/CA role and [no templates](https://serverfault.com/questions/320565/certificate-template-missing-from-certificate-template-to-issue) - which means the CA is "standalone", not "enterprise", confirmed via `certutil -getreg ca\catype`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\<masked>AD01-CA\CAType:

  CAType REG_DWORD = 3
    ENUM_STANDALONE_ROOTCA -- 3
CertUtil: -getreg command completed successfully.
```

There is also a "subordinate" CA running on a secondary DC that is "enterprise" (although its "templates" feature isn't working: "no templates found" errors when using Web Enrollment on it).

##### The question

Is this configuration ("standalone" root CA + "enterprise" subordinate CA) **capable** of issuing valid SSL certs for intranet sites like vCenter, SolarWinds, etc.?

###### Reason I ask:

Having [a lot of trouble](https://superuser.com/questions/1809986/can-ad-ca-certificates-for-internally-facing-sites-be-inherently-trusted) figuring out how to get a "trusted" SSL setup for internally facing (intranet) sites and could use any help I can get:

- [Can AD CA certificates for internally facing sites be inherently trusted?](https://superuser.com/q/1809986/239558)
- [Can Orion use an AD CA issued SSL cert?](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/product-forums/the-orion-platform/f/forum/100118/can-orion-use-an-ad-ca-issued-ssl-cert/314354#314354)

Figure this may have something to do with how CAs and DCs are currently set up.

If this is **not** OK and I need to switch to an "enterprise" CA, what's the easiest way to do so?

P.S. I am OK with it not being configured quite to specs with offline/online CAs and CAs not running on DCs - for now the only goal is to be able to issue good certificates to internally facing sites and apps.

Thanks!

Comment: It takes less than five minutes to use certreq and an inf file to create a certificate. Doesn't get much easier than that. Usually if someone needs help they include what they are doing that isn't working.

Comment: "Never install a certification authority on a domain controller in a production environment." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-cert-trust-validate-pki

Comment: *create* a certificate - maybe. Installing it properly and getting it trusted across the network - or even on a single machine? Haha. (I am a week into this, and not getting much closer: [Can AD CA certificates for internally facing sites be inherently trusted?](https://superuser.com/q/1809986/239558), lot more screenshots and what I tried here: "[Can Orion use an AD CA issued SSL cert?](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/product-forums/the-orion-platform/f/forum/100118/can-orion-use-an-ad-ca-issued-ssl-cert/314354#314354)"

Comment: "Never install a certification authority on a domain controller in a production environment." is not applicable to the question. There is fairly specific context that it does apply to, in that article ("Hello for Business", security hardening, **Lab**-based PKI), **none** of which are in play here. I have not found this to be a *requirement* in any other MS docs, only a security hardening *recommendation* and best practice.

Comment: The vendor PKI Design Guide describes Certificate Services on a Domain Controller as "not recommended" and a "worst case scenario". You probably aren't reachable, however anyone else should be aware this is not a good practice and should be avoided. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2901.public-key-infrastructure-design-guidance.aspx

Comment: `Figure this may have something to do with how CAs and DCs are currently set up.` As others have stated, certificate trust is not related to the setup of an authority. It's a fairly easy and straightforward client configuration as with all the other root certificates.

Comment: sorry, this flies high above my head: "certificate trust is not related to the setup of an authority". It's like saying, "system's functionality is unrelated to its configuration" - which is in conflict with everything I know about this world... :) As far as "fairly easy and straightforward client configuration" - I wish this was the case for me - and for a lot of other folks who seem to be utterly confused by getting trust to work. (I am happy it's easy for you though.)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Yes, it can**, and is a valid setup for SSL cert issuance even if it doesn't follow best security hardening practices.

- Note that the question isn't about security or any other implications, or whether this is a valid setup in production environment. The question was raised purely to resolve a problem of CA-issued intranet SSL certs not being trusted by browsers.
- Any other purposes, concerns and implications - other than SSL cert issuance - such as security, maintenance, configuration changes, etc. - are not in play here..
- Purely for intranet SSL cert issuance, this config appears to be valid. (Not sure if it bears repeating - yet the existing two answers seem confused about what the question is despite reiterating this in the text of the question.)
- Yes, it's not the best practice to have a CS/CA (Certificate Services / Certification Authority) role installed on a DC (as mentioned e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn786426(v=ws.11)#additional-roles-on-certification-authorities)) - yet that has nothing to do with the question.

Reason why I believe so:

- see no indications this is **not** a valid setup in Microsoft docs or other places (that it's not the best practice or even "strongly advised against" is irrelevant for the purpose of this question)
- Microsoft's warning, "**Never install a certification authority on a domain controller in a production environment**" only appears in **one** place of all Microsoft docs: under ["Lab-based PKI"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-cert-trust-validate-pki#lab-based-pki) in their "[Configure and validate the Public Key Infrastructure - on-premises certificate trust](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-cert-trust-validate-pki)".

  - The fact that it's under "Lab-based PKI" and not under, say, "Deploy an enterprise certification authority", tells me that it may only be relevant to... a "Lab-based PKI", and may not be a strict guideline for every other possible setup.
  - In all other places where it's advised to not install a CA on a DC (e.g. in "[Additional Roles on Certification Authorities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn786426(v=ws.11)#additional-roles-on-certification-authorities)" - which is a section in "[Securing PKI: Technical Controls for Securing PKI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn786426(v=ws.11))") - it's clear that it's *not* a hard requirement, but a *recommendation* from security and maintenance aspects.

P.S.

- I am very far from being an SME on this - this answer is based purely on reading relevant docs and a summary of comments on other answers, with the hope it'll help someone else in a similar situation. If a better answer shows up, I'll mark it as *the* answer.
- The whole reason I asked this question was this: could this ("standalone" root CA + "subordinate" enterprise CA) be an invalid config and the reason SSL certs get flagged as invalid in my environment? The answer appears to be a "no": this is not the reason our CA-issued SSL certs aren't trusted by our browsers - regardless of how ill-advised is to run a CA on a DC, it's something else. Onward... :)

Comment: Downvoted. The reason is that this answer may be harmful to other users who come to this web site. They may get a wrong impression that it is ok and good option to setup CA on DC only because it works. Technically, this setup will work, but it was never recommended. Answers provided on this board are intended to help other people too, thus we answer by considering potential negative implications. PKI is not an easy topic and you always should follow best practices and recommendation to avoid headaches in future.

Comment: oh that's OK - *of course* you prefer your own answer even if it betrays not reading the question in full and/or not understanding the context, as well as providing factually incorrect information :)

Comment: The Microsoft PKI Design Guide describes Certificate Services on a Domain Controller as "not recommended" and the "worst case scenario". Your self answer reeks of confirmation bias. There's a lot of reasons this is 180 degrees wrong. Just because it doesn't have a signed, numbered list from the vendor doesn't mean unorthodox configurations are "valid". https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2901.public-key-infrastructure-design-guidance.aspx https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Comment: "The question was raised purely to resolve a problem of CA-issued intranet SSL certs not being trusted by browsers" - If that were the case, then your question should have focused on that instead of all the discussion of a DC running CA services. Sorry, but it's a down vote from me, too.

Comment: Oh that's OK - thanks for at least letting me know. As to the downvote reason: the focus comes from **knowing what's relevant**. (But you already know that, right?) **I don't** - as people asking questions often don't. (It's all described and mentioned in the question - it's *really* strange seeing people who appear to be experts paying no attention to it and then downvoting - because they missed that context. Just super strange. But oh well.)

Comment: Asking the right question is often an interactive hand-holding process. Thanks for playing your part in it (not). :)

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT OK to run any certificate services on domain controllers. They must be installed on member servers only.

There are two reasons for that:

1. You won't be able to replace your domain controller if certificate services are installed on DC. As per best practices, DCs are replaced by adding new DC into network and then demoting and decommissioning old DC. You cannot demote DC with CA role. You will have to uninstall CA role first before you can demote DC.
2. Microsoft Certification Authority is a forest-wide resource. And in multi-domain environments, admins in one domain may affect other domains they don't have permissions in.

Comment: Thank you, @Crypt32! Does having a "subordinate" CA on a secondary DC change any of that? (Ability to replace or demote a DC running CA...)

Comment: P.S. The focus of the question wasn't security, availability, continuity, disaster recovery or any other implications or concerns other than this one: **ability to issue valid SSL certs**. If you were answering a question, "**Primary DC runs a Standalone CA - is that OK purely for the purpose of valid CA-issued SSL certs?**", with the focus on "standalone" - how would you answer that? (I didn't want the question to be too long and was hoping the added context was clear enough - looks like it wasn't. Both of the current answers are focussing on other aspects of the config and not cert issuance.

Comment: You are asking wrong question. You can't eliminate security and maintainability  aspects, so your rephrased question makes little sense. So the answer remains unchanged, i.e. it is not ok to have CA on DC.

Comment: Yes you can (eliminate security and maintainability aspects) for testing purposes - or when inheriting someone else's setup and the primary goal is to fix a specific issue, and worry about the rest later. If you can't answer it or think it's wrong - please don't. Delete it. I made that context crystal clear from the get go in several places in the text. The question was only rephrased to make that context appear in **four** places (rather than just two) and in the title.

Comment: P.S. I don't dispute that I don't know how to ask the right question - and that's because I  indeed don't (know what's relevant and what isn't) - which is *very* common when venturing into a relatively new territory. Getting pummelled for asking "wrong" questions and getting the question closed because of it - is quite unhelpful, mildly put. Instead, please **read the question in full** (or walk away if you have no time), and **help craft the right question**. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer. Another reason to not have the role in a DC is separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's not recommended to run a Certification Authority on a Domain Controller, regardless of it being stand-alone or Enterprise; also, what is even the point of installing a stand-alone CA on a domain computer (even more so on a DC)? The whole point of a stand-alone CA is not being integrated with Active Directory, it should run on a non-domain-joined computer.

Anyway, to answer your original question: while an Enterprise CA is automatically trusted by all domain members, a stand-alone CA is not; in order to make use of its certificates, and/or of certificates issued by a subordinate CA, you need everyone to trust its root certificate.

This can be done either using a GPO or using `certutil`; you can find more details here: [Publish root CA and sub ca certificate to the Trusted root certificate store](https://serverfault.com/questions/607912/publish-root-ca-and-sub-ca-certificate-to-the-trusted-root-certificate-store).

Comment: Thanks Massimo! The questions isn't asking *how* to get those SSL certs to be trusted (there's a linked question in the text, or perhaps we could ask a separate question which your answer would then be applicable to - I'll be happy to do so. The question is *only* asking whether this setup is *capable* of issuing valid SSL certs. (For which there's already an answer.)

Comment: Separately, the 1st paragraph of your answer ("not recommended", etc.) is stated and restated in the question itself, as well as in other answers that seem to miss that context. Please do no repeat it in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Finally, the core of your answer, that this setup's (standalone root CA + subordinate enterprise CA) certs aren't automatically trusted by domain members - should probably be well supported? Would you have a link to the appropriate docs and a quote from them?

Comment: @kindzmarauli I wrote this answer *exactly* to say "although it's not recommended, it should work if you do it right". The core of the answer is, you have to make your root cert trusted. This is true regardless of *where* your stand-alone CA is running.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft PKI Design Guide, a standalone CA on a domain controller should be used for lab environments. But it also depends on your organizations security policy.

Regarding trusted SSL, you would need to have the certificate chain available on devices. That could be the root ca certificate and if used the intermediate ca certificate. Using a group policy you can distribute the ca certificates to the clients.

Comment: Did you mean, "a standalone CA on a domain controller should be used for lab environments" **only**, i.e. should **not** be used in production environments? Would you know why, i.e. what are the adverse effects - not in terms of overall security but **purely** for the purpose of issuing valid and trusted SSL certs for intranet sites? (That's the gist of my question and I'd really rather not get into any other implications.)

Comment: That depends how business critical those intranet sites are, let's imagine you need to renew the certificate of those certificates, and for some reason your CA is down, is that acceptable or not? From a security point of view i wouldn't recommend it either. When a threat actor is able to land on that server he has access to your CA and your AD. So he is able to create fake websites with your cerficates and he is able to compromise identities. This is really a PKI Design question where you need to set your requirements.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2901.public-key-infrastructure-design-guidance.aspx (PKI Design Guide)

Comment: thanks but you are still not answering the question :)

Comment: Ok, i think a standalone CA should not be used in production environments.

Comment: let's forget about "production". The question is about cert issuance.

Comment: Can you update your initial post with what you want know /your conserns about cert issuing. It's not completely clear to me. But in general an enterprise can issue cerficates to computers and users in multiple domains.

Comment: I actually did (update the question with the context and the exact problem I am experiencing) - it's in the supplied links, yet the question I think can be answered with a "yes", it's a valid setup purely for cert issuance purposes - at least [MS TLG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831348(v=ws.11)) seems to think so as that's exactly what they're describing. (Except of course not installing a CA on a DC.)

Comment: Perhaps the question should remove the DC part altogether as it seems to be confusing everyone - I just wasn't sure it was relevant to purely cert issuance. E.g. "Standalone (online) CA + Subordinate Enterprise CA - OK purely for the purpose of valid intranet SSL certs?"

Comment: Intranet certs is too vague in my opinion, that's why i earlier talked about requirements? Are that web server cerficates? And how business critical is yout intranet, and do you have any security requirements for your intranet? Without knowing this someone says it's ok and someone else not, very subjective. If you have a security officer I think you would need to discuss your current setup with hin and also get his opinion.

Comment: not business critical, and criticality is not even in the scope of the question. The whole question stems from figuring out how to issue intranet SSL certs using AD CA and eliminate "not secure" and "certificate is not valid" browser flags. For the title question, the answer seems to be what I said above: "OK for that purpose, anything else notwithstanding" (just need to configure and use it right). "Security officer"? I am the one in this scenario. :)